# How to exclude the dots that fall out of 95th and 5th percentile of a trendline in a scatter plot?

Tags: excel, scatter, trendline

I made a scatter plot in Excel. I am wondering how to make a new scatter plot by excluding the dots that fall out of 95th and 5th percentile range of the trend line.

[image]

If there is no direct way, what are the steps manually to do this?

Comment: Add a helper column. You can use a formula to basically only return the value if it is within the 5th and 95th percentile. `=IF(A1 >=PERCENTILE($A$1:$A$13,0.05),IF(A1<=PERCENTILE($A$1:$A$13,0.95),A1,""),"")`

Comment: But there are two values (each dot has a x and a y), is it correct I do this for both x and y? I am  not quite sure. Thanks.

Comment: If you want between the 5th and 95th for both data sets, then yes.